# Pairing MKAnnotation to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, mkannotationview

Im trying to establish a link between custom MKAnnotationViews on a map, and custom UITableViewCells.

So far I've initiated every cell with an MKAnnotationView and then assigned the tag of the MKAnnotationView to the index.row of the cell, and then added this to an NSMutableArray. I've tested this and it works- each MKAnnotationView is linked to the appropriate UITableViewCell based on tag values and array position.

**The Problem**: When the user scrolls the table and the cell relating to MKAnnotationView goes out of frame, it seems to be being dequeued? The MKAnnotationView tag gets reset, although the pin stays on the map. Although I have managed to get text to persist in the cells of the UITableViewCells by using an array it isn't working for the MKAnnotationViews.

What would the best method me for to create a relationship between MKAnnotationViews on a map and UITableViewCells?

Comment: Don't store the views in an array.  Instead, store the underlying _model_ objects which are the objects that implement MKAnnotation (_the ones you pass to the MKMapView when calling addAnnotation_) in an array.  You have to be clear on your use of terminology and class/protocol names.  MKAnnotation is a protocol not a class.  MKAnnotationView is a view class.  id<MKAnnotation> is a model class that implements MKAnnotation.

Comment: Okay thanks, @Anna. I see what you're saying. Sorry re my terminology, I'm still trying to get to grips with MKAnnotationViews. So my answer lies in saving to an array from the addAnnotation method?

Comment: What I mean is: If you do `[mapView addAnnotation:myAnn];` then add `myAnn` to your array that you want to use as the data source for your table view.

Comment: Thanks, but that is what I've been already doing- where myAnn would be my own custom MKAnnotationView. This MKAnnotation view gets shown of the map and this gets added to my array   "<MapPin: 0xa860df0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0xa860fb0>>". Thoughts?

Comment: The object you give to addAnnotation is not supposed to be an MKAnnotationView.  It's supposed to be an object that just implements MKAnnotation (eg. `NSObject<MKAnnotation>`).  The MKAnnotationView is only created and returned in the viewForAnnotation delegate method.  I think you may have multiple issues that need to be solved one at a time.  The tableview cell dequeue problem may be unrelated to the problem of how the annotations are defined and added.

Comment: @Anna, I'm pretty much where I want to be now thanks to your explanation. If you want to add your explanation as an answer I'll gladly accept it for you?

Comment: Glad that the comments helped but feel free to answer it yourself "in your own words" with what worked for you.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Anna I've pretty much solved my problem.

I needed to go back and understand how the MKAnnotation protocol works. Now I have a custom NSObject class that conforms to the MKAnnotation protocol and gets it's title and coordinates from the users input in a UITableViewCell. This object is then added to an array at the index of the UITableViewCell that sent it.

Now I can access the correct MKAnnotation view based on the index of the custom object that conforms to MKAnnotationView protocol in an NSMutableArray, and the custom MKAnnotationViews persist on the mapView instead of being dequeued.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your problem is that you are trying to use views to store logic.
If I understand correctly, you must have an array of objects that should be represented two ways - as list of cells and as set of annotations on the map.

`UITableViewCell`s as well as MKAnnotationViews are reusable, they are only views that display some information at some point of time. No need to stick on that.

Every `UITableViewCell` has some object in datasource behind it.
Every `MKAnnotationView` has an `id<MKAnnotation>` object behind it.

So you can just have an array (which is ordered) of `<MKAnnotation>`-compatible objects and use that array as datasource to `UITableView`.

If at any point of time you need to find corresponding cell and annotationView, you can just use `objectAtIndex`:.

Comment: Thanks @hybridcattt, I sort of understand what you're saying, and I can now see why storing the MKAnnotations in an array was a bad idea. I originally had an array of cells alongside a separate array of MkAnnotationViews. How could I implement what you're suggesting though?

Comment: @afcgold, still you fill cells and annotation views from somewhere, why not have that array as a datasource to both.

Comment: maybe I should add that the mkannotations are dynamically added, they correspond to locations inputted into the tableviewcells, and as rows are inserted/deleted the mkannotationview has to stay tied to the correct cell. What kind of data should I be storing in an array for the mkannotations, coordinates?

Comment: In that case you need to have an array of some objects (they may also conform to MKAnnotation protocol) which represent your data entered to cell. When you add a cell (at bottom I assume) - you add new object to the array, when remove a cell - remove an object. And add/remove annotation views on the map correspondingly.

Comment: You can access corresponding cells from annotation by obtaining index 
NSInteger ind = [self.array indexOfObject:view.annotation]; UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[...ind...]];
And the other way around.